# Symfony3 - how can I add a photo using Symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony

I'm using Symfony3 and I want to know how can I add a photo to my website or a css file

Can anyone give me a detailed solution because I saw some people using the asset and they put their photos in `\public\images` and I didn't understand how it really works knowing that I don't have the folder `\public\images` in Resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html) to manage your assets (css, js, images). You can store them in the directory `app/Resources/public` and dump them before deploying to the production environment with the command `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`.

Comment: Symfony will generate your assets in the web directory with a public access and create links in your views. You can manipulate these assets however you want before serving them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I found a solution by myself
I store the images in src/nomDuBundle/Resources/public then I executed the command `php bin/console assets:install`.

A folder named Bundle will be created in /web , I found there my Bundle , I took the absolute PATH & in the twig file I used this code :

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/nomBundle/images/votreImage.png') }}" />
```

It works for those who have a problem with this

Answer (score 0):

**AppBundle**  is recommended by the [Assetic documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html) to centralize all ll that we need to include in the HTML header.

Is it why a new symfony generation with symfony phar always create a AppBundle ? In any case it is likely.

**src/AppBundle** directory is just like the ring of the Lord of the Rings, all power of front office is centered there. 
In it Create a **Resources** directory and  : **images**, **css**, **js**,**...** sub-directories.

```
src/AppBundle
             |
             -- Resources
                          |
                          --public
                                   |
                                   -- images
                                   |
                                   -- css
                                   |      
                                   -- js
                                   |
                            -- ....
```

install assetic with composer

configure config.yml

configure Appkernel :

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel{

public function registerBundles(){
    $bundles = [
                 ...
                 new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(), 
                 ... 
              ]
  ...
```

in twig views :

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

command line :

`$ php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Command line generates directories and image files with automatic names. And it works well.

```
web
    |
    -- images
    |
    -- css
    |
    -- js
    |
    -- ....
```